# Closing the browser event

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently developing a firefox extension and I need to know when the user closed the browser , so I can call a function. I've searched firefox addon sdk documentation and I haven't found anything. Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
require("sdk/system/unload").when(function(reason) {
    if (reason === 'shutdown') {
        handleShutdown();
    }

    if (reason === 'disable') {
        handleShutdown();
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like the correct way to me. Deleting my solution. Thanks @Nandu!

Answer (score 0):

tried this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

     window.onbeforeunload = function() { 

     var msg =" If you're not interested please let us know what we can do to improve."

               return msg; 

     }  });

</script>
```

Comment: i dont think i can use this. In my main.js I can't insert scripts , use jQuery or have access to window :)